# Vue email validation is not returning true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, email-validation

I am really new to Vue and for this project I am using email validation followed by `reg` on `VUE Script Data`. When I print out the `console.log(this.reg.test(this.email))` , while the user is filling the email input field, it validates correctly as true or false. `NEXT` button stays disable for both true and false case. Can we make the button enable, once the `console.log(this.reg.test(this.email))` is **true**.

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <input type="email" v-model="email" placeholder="enter email email address"/>
  <button v-bind:disabled="isDisableComputed">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    email: '',
    reg: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,24}))$/
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
      isDisableComputed() {
      if(this.reg.test(this.email) == 'true'){
        console.log(this.reg.test(this.email));
        return false;

      }
      else{
        console.log(this.reg.test(this.email));
        return true;
      }

    },
    
   }

})
```

**Below is my code uploaded on JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/9es2dLfz/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [MDN: RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), `RegExp.test` return **boolean**, not **one string**. So `this.reg.test(this.email) == 'true'` will be always false.

```js
let regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,24}))$/

console.log("regex.test('test@test.com')      ==> ", regex.test('test@test.com'))
console.log("regex.test('test@test.com')=='true'  ==> ", regex.test('test@test.com') == 'true')
console.log("regex.test('test@test.com')      ==> ", regex.test('test@test@.com'))
console.log("regex.test('test@test@.com')=='true'  ==> ", regex.test('test@test@.com') == 'true')
```

So uses `return !this.reg.test(this.email)` instead like the computed property=`isDisableComputed` in below snippet.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      reg: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,24}))$/
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isDisableComputed() {
        return !this.reg.test(this.email)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <input type="email" v-model="email" placeholder="enter email email address"/>
  <button :disabled="isDisableComputed">NEXT ({{isDisableComputed}})</button>
</div>
```